# oracle sleep or lock to check the processing

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, locking, sleep

I just want to see whether the data is getting inserted on the table or not..

So i have written like this:

```
select count(*) from emp;
dbms_lock.sleep(1);
select count(*) from emp;
```

So that it will sleep for 1 min . Even after sleep if the 1st count and 2nd count are different then the data is getting inserted into the table.

Otherwise the insertions are not happening.

But i have a small doubt regarding this, whether this instance will hang for 1 sec or the whole Database will hangon for 1 sec.

And if it wrong how to implement this.

Comment: "Even after sleep if the 1st count and 2nd count are different then the data is getting inserted into the table."  Bear in mind that if the other process is doing a batch insert the two counts will be the same unless the SLEEP() crossed the transaction boundary (i.e. the otehr process issued a commit in the interval).

Answer (score 3):

Only your PL/SQL-Block will be put to sleep. If you want to sleep for a minute, pass 60 (seconds) to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

You can use USER_LOCK.SLEEP if you don't want to grant EXECUTE to DBMS_LOCK which can be more destructive. The arguments are different however you can achieve the same thing.

USER_LOCK.SLEEP
PROCEDURE SLEEP
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?

---

TENS_OF_MILLISECS              NUMBER                  IN

DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP
PROCEDURE SLEEP
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?

---

SECONDS                        NUMBER                  IN

Answer (score 0):

To be more clear, you don't know whether or not the insertions are not happening; all you know is that the count of committed records didn't change.  If you have access to `V$TRANSACTION`, you can look at `USED_UBLK` and `USED_UREC` to verify that a transaction in flight is generating changes.

Answer (score 0):

How are you inserting into the table?  Is it batch?  OLTP?  I don't think what you proposed is pratical, but cannot suggest another way until more information is provided.  Give us a little more information on the process.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, sorry for my english :-D
AFAIK select count(*) is wasting resource. I suggest you create a trigger to increment number of rows inserted somewhere else. Your scheduled job then check the number of inserted rows and reset it to zero prior to exiting. In this way you will know whether any rows inserted between runs and how many.

```
create table emp_stat(inserted int);

insert into emp_stat values(0);
commit;

create trigger emp_trigger 
before insert on emp for each row 
begin 
    if ( inserting ) then 
        update emp_stat set inserted = inserted + 1; 
    end if; 
end;
```